# Is there an API to check if a passcode has been enabled on a user's Apple Watch?

Tags: watchkit, watchos

I'm implementing a security feature on a WatchOS app, I want the user to be able to use this feature only if a passcode has been enabled on the WatchOS device.

Is there a LocalAuthentication equivalent that I can use with WatchKit?

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for this in the watchOS platform. I'd file a suggestion with your developer account in Bug Reporter → watchOS + SDK.